# Change the values dynamically in anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to dynamically change the values of price and id with select of different drop downs in following anchor link. like If I select 3 days, the price changes to 24 in anchor and id with new oID.

Note: hidden fields are for data to submit in database. `$_post['deadline']`. Yes, correcting url. Type error.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="https://example.com?price=38&id=DS123">order</a>
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <label for="price" class="control-lable">Urgency*:</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="price" id="price" onchange="func()" required>
    <option  value="">Select urgency</option>
    <option  value="24">3 Days</option>
    <option  value="38">5 Days</option>
    <option  value="62">7 Days</option>
 </select>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="deadline" id="deadline" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="oid" id="oid" value="" />
```

Javascript

```
function func() {
var option = $("#price").val();
var dLine = $('#deadline').val();
var mID = new Date().getTime();
var oID = 'Q'+Math.round(mID/1000)

if (option =='24') {
  dLine = 3 Days;
  oID;
}

if (option =='38') {
  dLine = 5 Days;
  oID;
}

if (option =='62') {
  dLine = 7 Days;
  oID;     
  }
};
```

Comment: Then what to do with hidden fields?

Comment: I think you forgot to include the ? after .com https://example.com&price=38&id=DS123 should change to https://example.com?price=38&id=DS123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unnecessary hidden fields in HTML as well as unnecessary `if` conditions in jQuery(because i am unable to see and fruitfull use of those in your scenario)

Do it like below:-

```js
function func() {
  var option = $("#price").val();
  var mID = new Date().getTime();
  var oID = 'Q'+Math.round(mID/1000)
  $('.btn-warning').attr('href',"https://example.com?price="+option+"&id="+oID)
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <label for="price" class="control-lable">Urgency*:</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="price" id="price" onchange="func()" required>
    <option  value="">Select urgency</option>
    <option  value="24">3 Days</option>
    <option  value="38">5 Days</option>
    <option  value="62">7 Days</option>
 </select>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-warning" href="https://example.com?price=38&id=DS123">order</a>

<!-- not required <input type="hidden" name="deadline" id="deadline" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="oid" id="oid" value="" />-->
```

Note:-

Url:- `https://example.com&price=38&id=DS123` seems in-correct as it need to be `https://example.com?price=38&id=DS123` (check query-string notation `?` there)

Answer (score 1):

You can put an id in the anchor like:

`<a id="btn-order" class="btn btn-warning" href="#">order</a>`

Then in your onchange function (`func`), do something like:

`$('#btn-order').attr('href', 'https://example.com?price=' + option + '&id=' + oID);`

Answer (score 0):

rather than using onchange=func(), you can try to keep it clean by using jquery .on() :

```
    $('#price').on('change', function(e){
         var $thisSelect = $(this),
             $anchor = $('.btn.btn-warning'),
             oID = 'Q'+Math.round((new Date().getTime())/1000),
             newhref = 'https://example.com/?id='+oID+'&price='+$thisSelect.val(),
             selectedText = $thisSelect.find('option:selected').text();

         $anchor.prop('href', newhref);

         $('#deadline').val(selectedText);
         $('#oid').val(oID);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla js version:

```
function func () {
   var e = document.getElementById("price");
   var price = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   var button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-warning')[0];

   if (price && button) {
      var mID = new Date().getTime();
      var oID = 'Q'+Math.round(mID/1000);
      button.setAttribute('href', "https://example.com?price=" + price + "&id=" + oID)
   }
}
```